# When I plug my headphones into the Galaxy S 3 it won't let me use Google Play Music

Tags: google-play-music

It brings up a notification telling me that headphones have been plugged in and gives me about 5 apps to choose from. I can't change these apps and Play Music isn't one of them.

How can I use Google Play Music with my headphones?

Comment: Can you launch Google Play Music without headphones in? Perhaps there is some first-launch configuration that has to happen before it registers the Intent.

Comment: And what speaks against using the app drawer (or a widget placed on one of your homescreens) to simply start the music app, headphones plugged or not?